# R: How to use apply function in below code instead of loop

Tags: r, apply

I need to use any of the apply functions in my code instead of for loop.Below mentioned are sample code and functions.

Here is my data

```
  testdata<-data.table(x1=sample(1000),y1=sample(1000),x2=sample(1000),y2=sample(1000),h=sample(1000))
```

Here is my function

```
testfunction<-function(x0,y0,x1,y1,x2,y2,h){
  x<-x0+x1+x2+y0+y1+y2
  y<-x+x0+y0
  d<-x+y
  R<-x+y+d
  result <- data.frame(d,R,x,y)
  return (result)
}
```

my current code with for loop is

```
resultdf<-data.frame(d=NA,R=NA,x=NA,y=NA)
for (i in 1:nrow(reqdata.LN)){
    resultdf[i,]<-testfunction(x0=1.2,y0=2.1,testdata$x1[i],testdata$x2[i],
                               testdata$y1[i],testdata$y2[i],testdata$h[i])
}
```

I have tried using lapply and sapply but there are few errors

```
bb<-lapply(1:nrow(testdata),testfunction,x0=1.2,y0=2.1,testdata$x1[i],testdata$x2[i],
           testdata$y1[i],testdata$y2[i],testdata$h[i])
```

Can some tell how to use this apply functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As we have a `data.table`, the function can be directly applied as `+` is vectorized.

```
res <- testdata[, testfunction(x0=1.2, y0=2.1, x1, y1, x2, y2, h)]
head(res)
#      d      R      x      y
#1 3923.9 7847.8 1960.3 1963.6
#2 2689.9 5379.8 1343.3 1346.6
#3 4523.9 9047.8 2260.3 2263.6
#4 3535.9 7071.8 1766.3 1769.6
#5 3183.9 6367.8 1590.3 1593.6
#6 3677.9 7355.8 1837.3 1840.6
```

NOTE: The function in the OP's post returns a `data.frame`.  When we are using `data.table`, it is better to return it as `list` so that it will be a data.table object

```
testfunction<-function(x0,y0,x1,y1,x2,y2,h){
   x<-x0+x1+x2+y0+y1+y2
   y<-x+x0+y0
   d<-x+y
   R<-x+y+d
   list(d= d,R=R,x= x,y = y)

 } 

head(testdata[, testfunction(x0=1.2, y0=2.1, x1, y1, x2, y2, h)])
#      d      R      x      y
#1: 3923.9 7847.8 1960.3 1963.6
#2: 2689.9 5379.8 1343.3 1346.6
#3: 4523.9 9047.8 2260.3 2263.6
#4: 3535.9 7071.8 1766.3 1769.6
#5: 3183.9 6367.8 1590.3 1593.6
#6: 3677.9 7355.8 1837.3 1840.6
```

Comment: Thanks akrun. Actually the above function is example and it showing same result with both for loop and data.table code. But with my actual function it is giving different result with for loop and your data table code. Do you have any idea about it.

Comment: @PPC The function you created with `+` is vectorized.  Your actual function may not be the case.  You may have to create a new post with a function that mimics the original problem.

Comment: yes my actual function is not this simple and bit complicated. Data is confidential so i cannot share it. Is there any way to pass each element of a row to function through apply functions.

Comment: @PPC Without knowing the function, it is difficult to comment.  I guess the base R `apply` with `MARGIN =1` should work.

Comment: @PPC Without knowing the function, it is difficult to comment.  I guess the base R `apply` with `MARGIN =1` should work.